# How do I resize a GTK ComboBox(Text) to fit its contents?

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk3

I would like to add a `GtkComboBoxText` to the center of my widget, and take up the minimal amount of space required to display the largest item. So far I've tried to do this with a `GtkAlignment`, but the `GtkComboBox` does not expand to fit its content.

Below is a minimal example (in Haskell), but suggestions in any language would be appreciated.

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk

import Data.Text(pack)
import Control.Monad.Trans(liftIO)
import Control.Monad(mapM)

main :: IO ()
main = do
   initGUI

   window1 <- windowNew
   alignment1 <- alignmentNew 0.5 0.5 0.1 0.1
   comboboxtext1 <- comboBoxNewText

   mapM ((comboBoxAppendText comboboxtext1).pack) ["Foo", "Bar", "LongFooBarText"]

   containerAdd window1 alignment1
   containerAdd alignment1 comboboxtext1

   on window1 deleteEvent $ liftIO mainQuit >> return False

   widgetShowAll window1
   mainGUI
```